# in an MVC application login page is loading with a partial view

Tags: model-view-controller, view, partial

In an MVC application login page display as a partial view, if the login fails the message also showing the same partial view. but if the login success it redirect to the profile page but it not showing as page it acts as a partial view.

I used Ajax.BeginForm
     @using (Ajax.BeginForm("SignIn", "Home", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "result"))

in control 
    if (user != null)
       {

```
    SetMsg("Welcome , user.Name);
    return RedirectToAction("ProfileInfo", "Home");

   }
  else
    {
     SetMsg("Invalid user name or password");
     return PartialView("_Login",model);
    }
```

the issue is  ProfileInfo  page is not showing as a view.it is showing only a popup.

Comment: I solved the issue.

Comment: in control return as below   return Json(new { url = Url.Action("ProfileInfo") });    Then  in  partial view   @using (Ajax.BeginForm("SignIn", "Home", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "result", OnSuccess = "onSuccess" }))   then write  javasript function for  onSuccess   like  <script type="text/javascript">

        var onSuccess = function (result) {
            if (result.url) {               
                window.location.href = result.url;
            }
        }
   
    </script>